# Removing data within parenthese in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with a customer field that contains some data in parentheses.  For example --

customer

```
ABCDEFG Company, Inc. (Dallas, TX)
ABC Conglomerate International, Inc (New York, NY)
```

Is there a way to remove the data in the parentheses and leave the company name using SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assuming that, if parenthesis in the company name, then

**Query**

```
select 
replace(customer, concat('(',substring_index(customer, '(', -1)), '') as new_col_name
from your_table_name;
```

[**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1951f5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I see these examples and you want everything before the first open paren.  You can do this using:

```
select trim(substring_index(customer, '(', 1))
```

Comment: Used this option on another column with the same issue.  Thanks for the help.